# Disable client side decorations (CSD) on Wayland

Tags: qt, gtk, client-side, server-side, wayland

I am working on a Wayland Compositor, and I need to disable CSD for Qt and Gtk client apps.

Is there any environment variable I can use to do it so?

I have been searching without luck!

Answer (score 2):

For Qt, you can set `QT_WAYLAND_DISABLE_WINDOWDECORATION=1`

2021 Update (only relevant for compositor development):

There's now also an official protocol extension for negotiating window decorations, called [xdg-decoration](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland-protocols/-/blob/master/unstable/xdg-decoration/xdg-decoration-unstable-v1.xml), so if you're working on a compositor you can implement it and make sure to send a `configure` event with `server_side`:

```
    <event name="configure">
      <description summary="suggest a surface change">
        The configure event asks the client to change its decoration mode. The
        configured state should not be applied immediately. Clients must send an
        ack_configure in response to this event. See xdg_surface.configure and
        xdg_surface.ack_configure for details.

        A configure event can be sent at any time. The specified mode must be
        obeyed by the client.
      </description>
      <arg name="mode" type="uint" enum="mode" summary="the decoration mode"/>
    </event>
```

This would be the standardized and clean way to do it, but note however that toolkits are free to not implement this extension, so there's no guarantee that you will be able to use it.

If you're using the Qt Wayland Compositor API, the docs are [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwayland-compositor-xdgdecorationmanagerv1.html)

Qt clients implement and obey it and some other toolkits, but I don't think GTK does. It looks like they implement an unofficial extension developed by KDE, though, so if you really want to go out of your way to get rid of decorations on GTK, look into implementing [server-decoration](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/master/gdk/wayland/protocol/server-decoration.xml) as well.

Comment: This is not working for me, so in my main.cpp file I call qputenv("QT_WAYLAND_DISABLE_WINDOWDECORATION", QByteArray("1"));

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but are you sure you're setting the environment for the client(s) and not the compositor? If you set it in the client application itself, note that need to do it early in you main file (before your app is initialized).

Comment: Yes, I was setting it in the client. I tried what you suggested, however, and it did not work.