# How to disable client-side window decorations with GSettings overrides in Gnome (Wayland)?

Tags: gnome, wayland, gsettings

I would like to hide all client-side decorations in Gnome, by setting a GSettings override.

I am aware of [one SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130761/disable-client-side-decorations-csd-on-wayland), which is unsuitable because it targets extension developers.

I am also aware of [the undecorate extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4606/undecorate-window-for-wayland/), but besides not being supported in newer versions of gnome, this doesn't remove decorations across the board by default.

So - I would like a solution which just uses a GSetting override or otherwise fully disables decorations.

Comment: I'm quite sure what you're looking for doesn't exist...

Comment: I would just migrate to any OS that's not pushing CSD down user's throat. Fortunately I only have to sometimes use Ubuntu for work in a VM anyway, lucky me.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko I resent the assumption that I use Ubuntu. I'm a happy NixOS user for years. 

Joking aside, I do get the gist: use a more flexible desktop environment. Honestly, I am considering it...